# SQL - How to SUM a field inside a STRUCT that is being used in ARRAY_AGG

Tags: sql, arrays, struct, google-bigquery

I have a table that is using ARRAY_AGG on a few STRUCTs. So far, none of the values needed to be aggregated.

I added a new STRUCT and added it to a ARRAY_AGG but cannot understand how to sum a field in this new STRUCT.

There are currently 2 STRUCTs using ARRAY_AGG, **professor** and **class**. I am trying to add a 3rd STRUCT, **student** that sums the student.credits field.

My table currently looks something like this

| school_id | professor.gender | professor.age | class.type | class.name | student.name | student.credits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | 25 | Math | Algebra | John | 4 |
|  | M | 25 | Math | Algebra | John | 4 |
|  | M | 25 | Math | Algebra | Mary | 5 |
|  | M | 25 | Math | Algebra | Mary | 6 |
|  | M | 25 | Math | Algebra | Mary | 2 |

This is what I'm trying to make it look like (I want to sum the student.credits field)

| school_id | professor.gender | professor.age | class.type | class.name | student.name | student.credits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | 25 | Math | Algebra | John | 8 |
|  | M | 25 | Math | Algebra | Mary | 12 |

Any advice is greatly appreciated, I've been searching for a few days but haven't found an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the below query:

```
with sample_data as (
  select 1 as school_id, struct('M' as gender, 25 as age) as professor, struct('Math'as type, 'Algebra' as name) as class, struct('John' as name, 4 as credits) as student
  union all select 1 as school_id, struct('M' as gender, 25 as age) as professor, struct('Math'as type, 'Algebra' as name) as class, struct('John' as name, 4 as credits) as student
  union all select 1 as school_id, struct('M' as gender, 25 as age) as professor, struct('Math'as type, 'Algebra' as name) as class, struct('Mary' as name, 5 as credits) as student
  union all select 1 as school_id, struct('M' as gender, 25 as age) as professor, struct('Math'as type, 'Algebra' as name) as class, struct('Mary' as name, 6 as credits) as student
  union all select 1 as school_id, struct('M' as gender, 25 as age) as professor, struct('Math'as type, 'Algebra' as name) as class, struct('Mary' as name, 2 as credits) as student
),
agg_data as (
select 
  school_id, 
  array_agg(professor) as professor,
  array_agg(class) as class,
  array_agg(student) as student,
from sample_data
group by school_id
),

---------------
-- Query above is responsible for generating sample data
---------------

sum_data as (
select 
  school_id,
  professor[offset(index)].age,
  professor[offset(index)].gender,
  class[offset(index)].name,
  class[offset(index)].type,
  student[offset(index)].name as s_name,
  sum(student[offset(index)].credits) as credits,

from agg_data,
  unnest(generate_array(0,array_length(class)-1)) as index
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
)

select 
  school_id,
  array_agg(struct(age,gender)) as professor,
  array_agg(struct(name,type)) as class,
  array_agg(struct(s_name,credits)) as student
from sum_data
  group by school_id
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for the response!  
  
I did have a question on what is happening in the sum_data subquery, specifically this part: 
  
  
`from agg_data
  unnest(generate_array(0,array_length(class)-1)) as index
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6`

Is the GROUP BY just the total # of columns that are not being aggregated, in the table?  
  
  What is the reason for taking the `array_length(class)-1`?

Comment: Reddit user /u/bearinasuit17 was able to answer my question above.

  group by are the fields not being aggregated. The reason for taking array_length()-1 is because he generated an array with 0-based indexing - this is where 0 identifies the first element in the array (as opposed to 1-based indexing where 1 identifies the first element in an array).

So professor[0] would be the first record within that array. He's using OFFSET() to identify the 0-based index of the specified array. Refer to https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#accessing_array_elements